# ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'postgresql' database is not configured

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, heroku, heroku-postgres

I trying to figure out how fix the active record problem so I can push to heroku.

> -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
>          Running: rake assets:precompile
>          rake aborted!
>          ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'postgresql' database is not configured. Available: ["development", "adapter", "encoding",
>   "database", "host", "pool", "username", "password", "production"]

```
  development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: sample_app_development
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: sample_app
  password: 

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: sample_app_test
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: sample_app
  password: 


production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: sample_app_production
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: sample_app
  password:
```

Comment: @Amjad nailed it - remove spaces on 1st line in front of " development:"

Answer (score 5):

There is a space before `development` in the db config. I believe To fix it, simply remove space from the first line and follow the indentation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to write this command on terminal to create you database:

```
rake db:create
```

Then run `rake db:migrate` to run your migrations

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove spaces on 1st line "  development:"
2. Make sure of the database name e.g. "sample_app_development" or just "sample_app"
3. gem install pg
4. rake db:create
5. rake db:migrate

Comment: It was step #1 above that got me past my hour+ blockade -- didn't know leading spaces were an issue.

Answer (score 0):

First install postgresql

```
gem install pg
```

Then create project using following command:

```
rails new myapp -d postgresql
```

Comment: Thanks. I did this process first. My problem began once I did "git push heroku master"

Comment: I don't see any problem in your database.yml.